# How to upload whole folder from GlusterFS using API

Tags: glusterfs

Is it possible to upload whole folder with GlusterFS api at once? So far searching over https://github.com/gluster/glusterfs/tree/master/api could not find such option, only individual files operations.

Answer (score 1):

Your application needs to do this using the individual file operations in gfapi. If you don't want to write code do this recursively, you could perhaps create a fuse mount point and directly execute a coreutils command like `mv`or `cp` from your application to copy the folder to that mount.

Comment: I came to same conclusion - work with each file and folder, can't use fusemount because I'm doing my own fuse implementation